# Prevent mutt from uncollapsing threads after imap-fetch-mail

Tags: mutt

If I delete an email using another client, then run `:exec imap-fetch-mail` in mutt to have the email deleted in mutt, all threads in the folder become uncollapsed. Is there a way to prevent this?